# SDL Web 8.5 | To display message in TitlebarContainer

Tags: gui-extensions

Skinning the content manager explorer is already in place.

I have tried below option to add label in TitlebarContainer.

1. Created component to control show/hide of message in Titlebar.
2. Created javascript file to read configuration component[show/hide the message].
3. Added label[Value from component] next to "Breadcrumb" section in Titlebar through javascript.
4. Included javascript reference in **"web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Configuration\CME.config"** file.

   > ```
   > <group name="SDL.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Theme.Environments.Development">
   >    <fileset>
   >         <file type="style">{ThemePath}/Environments/FILENAME.CSS</file>
   >         <file type="script">{ThemePath}/Environments/CustomMessage.js</file>
   >   </fileset>
   > </group>
   > ```
5. Increased the value of the modification attribute in **"web\WebUI\WebRoot\Configuration\System.config"**

I have to re-write the script(if changes in "TitlebarContainer" elements) to use the label implementation in Tridion upgrades.

Adding a script reference in group **"SDL.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Theme.Environments.Development"** to implement this label is a valid approach ?.

Comment: I'll add an older example, though some elements might have changed since my example for Tridion 2011. What have you tried? Are you looking to add a label or a more temporary message?

Comment: @Alvin Reyes, My requirement is to Show/Hide message (a label). I tried an option to add label, please find the details in answer section.

Comment: Okay, see my comment to your answer. That information is better in your original question above or as a new question (basically can you reference a JavaScript file directly in the CME.config?).

Comment: **@Alvin Reyes:** Updated the question. I tried adding a javascript reference in CME.config and added the label. Not sure whether it is recommended or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use the *environment name* for that message, you can follow the instructions to [skin the Content Manager Explorer for SDL Web 8.5](https://docs.sdl.com/792152/394476/sdl-web-8-5/skinning-the-content-manager-explorer).

I created an older example, but [for SDL Tridion 2011 on Tridion Developer](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/where-am-i-skinning-the-sdl-tridion-content-manager-explorer). The main part was to **uncomment and update the `environment > name` node in `CME.config`**:

```
<environment>
    <name>CreateAndBreak</name>
    <resourcegroup>...</resourcegroup>
</environment>
```

Otherwise other options for setting a message could be:

- Custom page to point to a page with instructions as a default page for users to see
- A slide-out navigation integration or label to set some text and/or page
- JavaScript, Ajax, or similar pop-up in a basic GUI extension

Though you could *try* to modify CME files, I wouldn't recommend that as it's not a valid extension approach and could/will change in an upgrade.